# How do I write a function that checks if the number of child elements has changes in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parent-child, onchange

Im currently using an if test to check how many child elements the parent element got

```
if(document.getElementById("a").childNodes.length <  1){...}
if(document.getElementById("b").childNodes.length <  1){...}
```

but I want a function that runs every time it changes.
I will be using this function on several elements.

Comment: That's a very broad question. Entire libraries have been built around checking for changes. React, Knockout, Ember, etc. etc. Two way data binding is a very old problem.

Comment: Okay, let me spesify, I want a function that checks if a <div> has gotten a <img> tag inside it

Comment: So use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on the `<div>`.

Comment: Use mutation observers.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to make it work